# Minimizing sum of absolute values

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces, absolute-value, quadratic-programming

here is my objective function:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{}{\text{minimize}}
& & \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha|x_i| + (1-\alpha)|x_i-c|  \\
& \underset{}{\text{s.t.}}
&& 0 \leq \alpha \leq 1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

I am wondering if it is possible to express this as a quadratic problem in order to solve it using the corresponding techniques.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you optimizing over alpha? If so, this problem is linear.

Comment: If this is indeed a minimization over alpha, then either alpha = 0 or alpha = 1 is optimal, depending on the sign of the sum of |x_i| - |x_i - c|. You can just take out the 1 from 1-alpha as it does not depend on alpha, and pull the alpha before the remaining sum.

Comment: Yes it is a minimization over alpha and also over c.